# Angular filter list without ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there any good way of using angular to filter a list WITHOUT ng-repeat? I dont want to use javascript to draw the list at first, but i want to use angular to filter it afterwards.

Example:

```html
<input type="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search for fruits!" />

<ul>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
```

I want to use the search box to filter the existing html.

(Please dont give any examples with ng-repeat or jQuery in general)

Comment: There is probably no way to do this using angular filters. You'd have to write your own filtering method than.

Comment: @m.brand Using angular filters and ngRepeat is natural way to do it. Without it it's also pretty simple though.

Comment: You can write a very simple directive to do it.

Comment: Yea, true. It just won't be as simple as putting the filter as you would with a ng-repeat.

Comment: @m.brand Yes, but OP is probably lookig for other interesting way for lerning purpose. Why not!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can write a simple directive to handle show/hide:

```
app.directive('filterList', function($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var li = Array.prototype.slice.call(element[0].children);

            function filterBy(value) {
                li.forEach(function(el) {
                    el.className = el.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ? '' : 'ng-hide';
                });
            }

            scope.$watch(attrs.filterList, function(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                    filterBy(newVal);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and use it this way:

```
<input type="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search for fruits!" /> {{search}}

<ul filter-list="search">
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
```

There are a couple of benefits of using a directive:

1). You don't have to put any `ngShow/ngIf` directives on every `li`.

2). It will also work with a new appended `li` elements to the list.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/wpqlYkKeUTfR5TjVEEr4?p=preview

Comment: That's great, I can use it in some projects. :)

Comment: Thanks, but if there are some collapsing operations on that menu and sub menus, it is not working anymore when you search and then clear the search, is there anyway to fix?

Comment: @tinyCoder depends on how this "collapsing" happens

Comment: It is here in the sidebar, please take a look: https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index.html#

Comment: I suggest isolating the problem in separate plunk, you can fork the one i posted in the answer, then it will be simpler to check.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ng-show/ng-hide and compare them to the value of the li's.

Example:

```html
<input type="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search for fruits!" />

<ul>
  <li ng-show="matches('Banana')">Banana</li>
  <li ng-show="matches('Apple')">Apple</li>
  <li ng-show="matches('Orange')">Orange</li>
</ul>
```

And in your js:

```
$scope.matches = function (text) {
   var pattern = new Regexp(text, "gi")
   return pattern.test($scope.search);
}
```

But this is just bad... It's a lot easier with ng-repeat/filter!

Comment: ng-repeat just isn't SEO friendly (and all that) enough for this case :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using `ngIf`, `ngShow` or `ngHide`.

```html
<input type="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search for fruits!" />

<ul>
  <li ng-if="matches('Banana')">Banana</li>
  <li ng-if="matches('Apple')">Apple</li>
  <li ng-if="matches('Orange')">Orange</li>
</ul>
```

```
$scope.matches = function(str) {
    return str.indexOf($scope.search) >= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make it as Michel Tome wrote just more generic way.

```
<input type="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search for fruits!" />

<ul>
  <li ng-show="isSimilar($event)">Banana</li>
  <li ng-show="isSimilar($event)">Apple</li>
  <li ng-show="isSimilar($event)">Orange</li>
</ul>
```

And in the JS take the text from the event.

```
$scope.isSimilar = function ($event) {
   var text = $event.target.textContent;
   var pattern = new Regexp(text, "gi")
   return pattern.test($scope.search);
}
```