# How search text inside html by ng-model?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

html:

```
        <div style='width:450px;'>
            <div style='float:right;'>
                <input ng-model='search'  />
            </div>
            <div style='float:right;'>Search:</div>        
        </div>
        <div style='width:450px;'>
            <div>Logan Cale</div>
            <div>Darien Fawkes</div>
            <div>John Crichton</div>
            <div>Michael Scofield</div>
            <div>John Wick</div>                
        </div>
```

Somehow I need to hide/show `div` blocks with names based on value user enter in `input`. There is some easy way?

Comment: Here is exactly what you are asking about: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26608693/949476

Comment: it working with ng-repeat? or there is diference?

Comment: There is no ngRepeat involved. Check the answer on more time, the only difference is that you have divs, and in the answer there is ul and li.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
    <div style='width:450px;'>
        <div style='float:right;'>
            <input ng-model='search'  />
        </div>
        <div style='float:right;'>Search:</div>        
    </div>
    <div style='width:450px;' ng-hide="search == 'hi'">
        <div>Logan Cale</div>
        <div>Darien Fawkes</div>
        <div>John Crichton</div>
        <div>Michael Scofield</div>
        <div>John Wick</div>                
    </div>
```

Now type "hi" inside the input to hide the bottom div