# How to Filter list of items based on search text in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I have static list of items like..

```
<input type="text" ng-model="filter">
<ul>
            <li class="menu-heading Heading-mob">PERSONAL SETTINGS</li>
            <li class="active first_child hvr-bounce-to-left">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Password", "Account")" target="_blank">
                    <i class="nc-icon-mini objects_key-26"></i>
                    <span>Change Password</span>
                </a>
                <a href=""><i class="nc-icon-glyph ui-3_card-add no-border"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="hvr-bounce-to-left">
                <a href="@Url.Action("AccountInfo", "Account")" target=" _blank">
                    <i class="nc-icon-mini ui-e_square-e-info"></i>
                    <span>Account Information</span>
                </a>
                <a href=""><i class="nc-icon-glyph ui-3_card-add no-border"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="hvr-bounce-to-left">
                <a href="@Url.Action("SecurityQuestion", "Account")" target="_blank">
                    <i class="nc-icon-mini ui-1_lock-open"></i>
                    <span>Security Question</span>
                </a>
                <a href=""><i class="nc-icon-glyph ui-3_card-add no-border"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-heading active ">APP SETTINGS</li>
            <li class="hvr-bounce-to-left" ng-click="selectAppSetting('userType')">
                <a ui-sref="appSetting.userTypeList" ng-class="{'active': selectedAppSetting === 'userType'}">
                    <i class="nc-icon-mini users_single-04"></i>
                    <span>User Types</span>
                </a>
                <a href=""><i class="nc-icon-glyph ui-3_card-add no-border"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="hvr-bounce-to-left" ng-click="selectAppSetting('App Templates')">
                <a ui-sref="appSetting.appTemplates" ng-class="{'active': selectedAppSetting === 'App Templates'}">
                    <i class="nc-icon-mini users_single-04"></i>
                    <span>App Templates</span>
                </a>
                <a href=""><i class="nc-icon-glyph ui-3_card-add no-border"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="hvr-bounce-to-left" ng-click="selectAppSetting('PublishApps')">
                <a ui-sref="appSetting.publish" ng-class="{'active': selectedAppSetting === 'PublishApps'}">
                    <i class="nc-icon-mini ui-2_grid-48"></i>
                    <span>Publish Apps</span>
                </a>
                <a href=""><i class="nc-icon-glyph ui-3_card-add no-border"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="hvr-bounce-to-left" ng-click="selectAppSetting('Roles')">
                <a ui-sref="appSetting.roleList" ng-class="{'active': selectedAppSetting === 'Roles'}">
                    <i class="nc-icon-mini users_square-32"></i>
                    <span>Roles</span>
                </a>
                <a href=""><i class="nc-icon-glyph ui-3_card-add no-border"></i></a>
            </li>
 </ul>
```

In the above code i have list of static items i am not using ng-repeat . I have textfield. when i enter text on input text i want to filter list using AngularJs. The input type text contains ng-model="filter" so where i use pipe symbol for filter list of the items in ul tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide a filter to the element using ng-repeat. So implement a ng-repeat.

First construct an object and encapsulate it in array. 
Then iterate that array with ng-repeat

Eg.

```
var arrayItems=  [{url: 'something1', text: 'accountInformation'}];//add other information as necessary in object.

<input type="text" ng-model="search">
<ul>
  <li>Personal settings</li>
  <li ng-repeat="item in arrayItems | filter:search">
    <a href="item.url" target="_blank">
                <i class="nc-icon-mini objects_key-26"></i>
                <span>{{item.text}}</span>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

**Update**: For a solution without ng-repeat. Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608355/angular-filter-list-without-ng-repeat).

Comment: Ya That is Correct . I know using filter with ng-repeat , But i want to filter without using ng-repeat

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you  @MegaRacer for Proving the link. That is working fine

Comment: That's great ! Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you achieve what you wanted. :)